# Multiple Applications Listening on Same Socket using SO_REUSEPORT

Tags: linux, networking, network-programming

If we have set `SO_REUSEPORT` on our sockets, then we can have multiple of them listening on the same `IP:Port` condition at the same time. I read through multiple blog posts on the below doubt, but it was still unclear to me how all the dynamics are being taken into account.

Let suppose there are two different processes A & B, assume that they are "listening" on the same `IP:Port`. Now if a new request comes in for an endpoint which is to be served by process B and not A, how does the OS know about which process to transmit this request?

Comment: It's *indeterminate* (look at it as *random*) which process will get the connection.

Comment: So it might happen that the request goes to the wrong process altogether?

Comment: Yes that's correct. If you have different processes that do different things then use different ports.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Answer. **It doesn't.**

Let's see what happens when a socket is opened by a process.

`listen()` system call tells the linux kernel that *"hey, please be ready for some of the requests directed at me"*

At this point, two queues corresponding to this socket is assigned, namely SYN and Accept Queues.

**SYN Queue:** When a `SYN` packet to this `IP:Port` arrives, the kernel puts that into this queue and sends back `SYN-ACK`. At this point the connection state is `SYN-Received`.

*Note that, if there are two SYN Queues for two different sockets listening to the same `IP:Port` combination, kernel `randomly` assigns that packet to one of them, even if that packet was setting up the foundation for the actual requests to the other socket/process.*

**Accept Queue:** When `ACK` arrives from the client, the connection state is changed to `ESTABLISHED` and the actual connection object is shifted to the Accept Queue of the socket. There are bunch of more validations performed here but are irrelevant to the question.

The process which spawns the socket, continuously calls the `accept()` system call, which basically pops out request from its own Accept Queue and processes it.

So as we can deduce from above, the kernel simply puts the incoming request randomly to one of the listening sockets and it is possible that the selected socket is not the one supposed to process the request, in which case the client request will eventually timeout.